# How to modify a website form using Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, webview

Say I have an app that has the user enter information, then I want to transfer that information to my website which has textfields.

I know I need to create a webview, but how can I modify things in that webview?

If the user types in "Hello" in the `EditText` in my app then clicks on a button "ToWebsite", I want to take what they typed in, go to the website which also has a field to type in something, and copy that "Hello" into that field. How would I achieve this?

I know how to create a webview and stuff, I just need to know how to access stuff in the webview.

Comment: take the backend of your website and create an api... sending data to fill forms from android to a website without just loading your webview sounds hacky...

Comment: I will load the webview though

Comment: so then what is the problem? if you load a webview in your app its the same form fields as your website.